# VMware module compilation problem: Failed to build vmmon

Tags: compiling, vmware

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and just installed VMware Workstation Player from vmware.com.

Installation was successful, however I need to "compile and load several modules". I get an error message with a reference to a logfile containing the following:

```
2018-05-29T15:15:03.143+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=4539 version=14.0.0 build=build-6661328 option=Release
2018-05-29T15:15:03.143+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.143+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2018-05-29T15:15:03.143+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Host is Linux 4.15.0-22-generic Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/oholub/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/oholub/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/oholub/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/oholub/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/oholub/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.142+02:00| vthread-1| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/oholub/.vmware/preferences. Using default values.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.178+02:00| vthread-1| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-4539.log
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting header path for 4.15.0-22-generic to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.185+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:03.189+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.189+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:03.315+02:00| vthread-1| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-29T15:15:03.315+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Read 22724 symbol versions
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.330+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.332+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.332+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.333+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.333+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.334+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.334+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.335+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.335+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.336+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.346+02:00| vthread-1| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2018-05-29T15:15:03.356+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.356+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting header path for 4.15.0-22-generic to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.357+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.357+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:03.357+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.357+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:03.361+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.361+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:03.485+02:00| vthread-1| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-29T15:15:03.485+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Read 22724 symbol versions
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.500+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:03.504+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.504+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:03.505+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2018-05-29T15:15:03.507+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Got gcc version "7".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.507+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.509+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Got gcc version "7".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.509+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.510+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:03.514+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.514+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:03.515+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.515+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.515+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:03.515+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.515+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:03.519+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.519+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:03.519+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.520+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.520+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting header path for 4.15.0-22-generic to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.520+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.520+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:03.520+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.520+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:03.525+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.525+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:03.649+02:00| vthread-1| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-29T15:15:03.649+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.664+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Read 22724 symbol versions
2018-05-29T15:15:03.664+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.666+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.818+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.818+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-05-29T15:15:03.826+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-05-29T15:15:03.826+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-HyCpoM/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-05-29T15:15:05.087+02:00| vthread-1| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-05-29T15:15:12.980+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:15:12.981+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:12.981+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:12.981+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:12.981+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:12.997+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:12.997+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:12.998+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.001+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-29T15:15:13.001+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting header path for 4.15.0-22-generic to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.001+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.001+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:15:13.001+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:15:13.001+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:15:13.018+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.018+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:15:13.162+02:00| vthread-1| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-29T15:15:13.162+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-29T15:15:13.177+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Read 22724 symbol versions
2018-05-29T15:15:13.177+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.179+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:15:13.852+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.852+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-05-29T15:15:13.858+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-05-29T15:15:13.858+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-iVCEwi/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-05-29T15:15:15.149+02:00| vthread-1| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-05-29T15:22:35.368+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:22:35.368+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.368+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:22:35.368+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:22:35.368+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:22:35.386+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.386+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:22:35.386+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.390+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-29T15:22:35.390+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting header path for 4.15.0-22-generic to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.390+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.390+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:22:35.390+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:22:35.390+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:22:35.407+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.407+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:22:35.570+02:00| vthread-1| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-29T15:22:35.570+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-29T15:22:35.585+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Read 22724 symbol versions
2018-05-29T15:22:35.585+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-29T15:22:35.587+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:22:36.270+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-05-29T15:22:36.271+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-05-29T15:22:36.293+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-05-29T15:22:36.293+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-iuxjWq/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-05-29T15:22:37.666+02:00| vthread-1| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2018-05-29T15:28:42.907+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2018-05-29T15:28:42.907+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:28:42.908+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:28:42.908+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:28:42.908+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:28:42.926+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:28:42.926+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:28:42.926+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2018-05-29T15:28:42.930+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2018-05-29T15:28:42.930+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting header path for 4.15.0-22-generic to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include".
2018-05-29T15:28:42.930+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:28:42.930+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2018-05-29T15:28:42.930+02:00| vthread-1| I125: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2018-05-29T15:28:42.930+02:00| vthread-1| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc-7 for preprocess check
2018-05-29T15:28:42.949+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.15.0-22-generic".
2018-05-29T15:28:42.949+02:00| vthread-1| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.15.0-22-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2018-05-29T15:28:43.090+02:00| vthread-1| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers
2018-05-29T15:28:43.090+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2018-05-29T15:28:43.105+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Read 22724 symbol versions
2018-05-29T15:28:43.105+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2018-05-29T15:28:43.107+02:00| vthread-1| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2018-05-29T15:28:43.768+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2018-05-29T15:28:43.768+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2018-05-29T15:28:43.779+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2018-05-29T15:28:43.779+02:00| vthread-1| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-AxTjsm/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2018-05-29T15:28:45.153+02:00| vthread-1| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Thanks for any help, I am kind of lost in this.

Comment: It looks like installation was not successful. Please reinstall

Comment: Thanks for the answer, during the installation I noticed a following message:

    `(vmware-installer.py:15147): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"`